# CodeIgniter: How to move one column value to another with Where condition using active record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, model

I want to move one column value to another e.g. there are two table columns 'Location', 'Call_Location'
I want to move all values of 'Call_location' to 'Location' column with a condition of selected date range only. How will do it in codeigniter.

```
$text = "UPDATE phone_acc SET location = call_location WHERE dt >= 
dateformat(current_date, '%Y-%m-01')
AND dt < dateformat(current_date, '%Y-%m-01') + interval 1 month;
$this->db->query($text);
```

This is not working.

One of the issue found out that it is taking the second field name as a string value 'call_type' whereas it should take it as a field name.

```
    UPDATE `phone_acc` SET `location` = 'call_type' WHERE `call_date` = '2020-11- 
   01 01:33:51'
```

Comment: what you actually want??

Comment: copy of a column value into another column. it is kind of bulk update which will effect thousands of record.

Comment: both column datatypes are same??

Comment: yes string. seems no issue in query. but still it is not working. no issue at db side.

Comment: do I need to use update_batch()

Answer (score 1):

Your query is missing the condition on the current month. Assuming that the date is stored in column `dt`, you would do:

```
UPDATE phone_acc 
SET location = call_localtion 
WHERE id = 50959757 AND dt >= dateformat(current_date, '%Y-%m-01')
```

This copies one value from one column to another *on the same row*, for every row that satisfies the `where` predicates.

If you have future dates in your data, use an upper bound too:

```
dt >= dateformat(current_date, '%Y-%m-01')
AND dt < dateformat(current_date, '%Y-%m-01') + interval 1 month
```

Comment: Sorry I missed the date in my query I edited the post. But that is not the problem I am facing. Its like a bulk update which is effecting thousands of record. query runs and in the end it says page cannot be found error....but even a single selected record is not updating. no idea whats going wrong.